# Mvc Windows Auth on same machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

i am trying to get my Local machines IIS Server to validate me as a user in my mvc 3 site using the Razor Engine. i have my site and AppPools created and work properly if i have Anon auth enabled but the second i turn on windows authentication and disable anon authentication it keeps throwing a 401.2 error.

my web.config is as follows.
`

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

</appSettings>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <profile>
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index" />
            <add value="index.cshtml" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

`
can anyone tell me what i have to change\do to get it to work.

my host file has been updated with the following.

`127.0.0.1 dev.local.mysite.com`

and the site has been setup with the bindings pointing to dev.local.mysite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone has this problem the solution to my problem came in the form

under regedit go to

```
/HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
```

add a REG_MULTI_SZ value called

```
BackConnectionHostNames
```

and put the wanted URL into the Registry Entry